# Entity framework always returning Id 1 when adding contact?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext

I created a test and it kind of works when I save an object, the problem is that the creation of an object always returns the Id = 1 no matter how many insertions I make, so when I set that same variable as the id it goes and grabs the first one in the table instead of the just inserted one, here is the code:

```
using (DbContextTransaction tx = this.Context.Database.BeginTransaction())
{
    CustomPerson con = new CustomPerson();
    con.Name = "John";
    con.LastName = "Smith";

    this.Context.CustomPersons.Add(con);

    //here tempId it's always 1 (why), but it inserts the record with a different id
    long tempId= this.Context.SaveChanges();

    CustomPerson newPerson = (CustomPerson)this.Context.CustomPersons.Find(tempId);
    Assert.AreEqual(newPerson.Name, con.Name);
    tx.Commit();
}
```

And with this it will go and retrieve the record at position 1 in the table, instead of the newly created one in the table which is a value greater than 1 always.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MSDN documentation for `DbContext.SaveChanges` says:

> Return Value
>
> Type: System.Int32
>
> The number of objects written to the underlying database.

It's not the ID of the record.  It's the number of records.  That should have been obvious because what if you had added more than one entity before saving?  How could you get IDs for all of them?  You're always saving one record so you get the value 1 returned.

If you want the ID of the entity then you have to get the value from the appropriate property after saving it.

Comment: aha.. that's what i was missing.. hmm i understand. Thanks a lot! (first pass at entity framework :) ).

Comment: If ever something doesn't work the way you expect, READ THE DOCUMENTATION.  The fact that this is your first experience with EF makes that even more important.  I can't imagine how many man hours was spent writing the MSDN Library reference documentation and it's simply ignored by so many people.  If you are using a particular method or type and haven't read its documentation then posting a question here is premature.

Comment: You are right, i did read but missed the number of objects part.. Thank you!, i had a lot done today and my eyes are tired. I accept the reprimand respectfully.

Answer (score 2):

After saving new customer, the `Id` property of `CustomPerson` will set by `EF` and `Context.SaveChanges` returns number of inserted records.